# Create a dynamic list from multiple criteria in data block

Tags: excel

How do I create a list from multiple criteria ?

```
Item    Type    Data1   Data2   Data3   Data4
Apple   Fruit   81      15      14      11 
Apple   Fruit   77      73      59      42 
Cashew  Nut     16      6       1       1 
Cashew  Nut     100     51      21      12 
Peach   Fruit   75      54      5       2 
Apple   Fruit   64      12      11      1 
Apple   Fruit   47      31      24      15 
Peach   Fruit   6       6       1       0 
Peach   Fruit   68      58      56      47
```

Criteria = Fruit & (Data2 or Data3 or Data4)>20

Result (Formatted List of Items with No Gaps)

```
Apple
Peach
Apple
Peach
```

Answer (score 0):

This can actually be worked out using the [INDEX function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INDEX-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a) in its *array form*.

[image: Apples and Peaches]

The formula in H2 is,

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A$2:A$99, SMALL(INDEX(ROW($1:$98)+(((B$2:B$99="fruit")+(((D$2:D$99>20)+(E$2:E$99>20)+(F$2:F$99>20))>0))<>2)*1E+99, , ), ROW(1:1))), "")
```

Fill down as necessary to catch all of the results and maybe a few rows more for future consideration. You will probably wish to put *Fruit* and *20* in separate cells and reference the cells within the formula rather than edit the formula itself for different criteria.

When editing this formula for your own purposes, remember that `ROW(1:98)` is the *position within* `A2:A99` and not the actual row on the worksheet. `ROW(1:1)` is simply a counter for the `SMALL` function's *k* parameter and will increase (e.g. *1, 2, 3, 4, etc*) as you fill the formula down.

This is a standard formula. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter↵</kbd> is neither necessary or desired.

Comment: Mate ... you're an absolute legend ! I have spent so long trying to solve this one

Comment: Sorry ... but if I want to change the columns I pick from (Dynamically) how do I tell the formula to look in different columns ? Thankyou

Comment: That would really depend upon what you *exactly* mean by 'dynamically'. That statement is pretty broad. If describing your new situation is too long for an addendum to your original question, I'd suggest you close this off and start a new one with the updated formula.

Comment: Sorry ... all I'm saying is that instead of hard coding the Data2, Data3 , Data4 columns into the formula, can I have a lookup function to decide which column to check for the numbers > 20 ?

Comment: Probably best to use a separate qty for each of the data columns. If a data column is not to be considered, use -1 as the qty. That will always be true so it is if there were no criteria for that column.

Comment: I can get what I'm after with this EXCEPT I can't get it to test if the columns are > or < 20 ?                                                                 =IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$99, SMALL(INDEX(ROW($1:$98)+((($B$2:$B$99="fruit")+(((MATCH("Data2",$C$1:$F$1,0)=2)+(MATCH("Data3",$C$1:$F$1,0)=3)+(MATCH("Data4",$C$1:$F$1,0)=4))>0))<>2)*10000000000, , ), ROW(1:1))), "")