# Excel formula for creating a list using predefined criteria

Tags: arrays, excel, list

The array formula I need is to create a list of unique divisions based on the country that is entered in cell (A1) for only divisions that have forecasted sales. The raw data sheet the list is pulling off is called 'Forecast' and has the following information:

Column A = Country, Column B = Division, Column C = Forecasted Sales, Column D = Forecast month

As the forecast data is broken into months, each division is repeated 24 times (for the 24 month forecast) so the formula will need to be able to return one record while eliminating the rest.

The closest solution I have found is this entry however I was unable to tailor it to my situation: [Create a dynamic list from multiple criteria in data block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28709911/create-a-dynamic-list-from-multiple-criteria-in-data-block)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) because '*I've been searching for an answer to a formula issue for a few days and I've found different variations that come close but do not quite fit what I am after.*' is **not** a specific programming problem and making pleas for assistance like '*Any help would be greatly appreciated.*' does nothing to change that.

Comment: Appreciate the feedback Jeeped - I am merely highlighting that although my issue is not unique in nature, I have researched existing solutions proposed in this forum as well as others without being able to find a resolution (and I'm not asking for assistance without trying to resolve the issue on my own)

Comment: If you want someone to help you with your own efforts then [edit] your question to include what you have come up with so far and note any errors that you have received and what it is not doing that you want it to do. If you want a swarm of people to jump to your assistance then plase provide a [mcve].

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. Post a data sample, a screenshot, if you must, post the expected result and explain the logic in context. Sounds very much like a Pivot Table could do it. Why the need for a formula and how come you know you need an array formula at that? It looks to me as if you're asking an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)